# High Sierra - Switch focus on windows when switch workspace

Tags: mac, mission-control

I would like to change the current behaviour of my high sierra OS.

**Below is the process of what happen:**

1. Open Mail on Workspace 1
2. Open Safari then open it in full screen mode (you have two workspaces now: Workspace 1 and Safari full screen mode, ctrl+cmd+f)
3. Go back to Workspace 1
4. The focus is still on Safari and not Mail.

**What I would like to change:**
-> The focus is on Safari and I would like to have the focus on Mail, the current workspace where I am. The goal is to use my shortcuts on Mail and not Safari without clicking on the window.

Is it possible to have this behaviour ?
On other multi-desktop OS, it's working like that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The focus should be on the last app that was frontmost the last time you used that Space. If you Cmd/Tab rather than directly switch Spaces, that may work better for you; otherwise you're going to have to click the first time, or fix apps to specific Spaces.

Comment: This is so stupid. I would just expect this to work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a series of apps to make your workflow more comfortable. An app like [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/downloads/) can be used to switch applications, or workspaces, with a trackpad gesture or other button.

A somewhat older app, like [Focus 2](http://eerko.nl/software/focus-2/), can be used to provide a visual indicator icon of the focused application (works best if you only have 1 monitor). When configured properly, it eliminates having to read the application's name in the Menu Bar, as a peripheral glance is all that is needed.

Finally, TotalSpaces can eliminate the annoying animation that happens when you switch spaces.

This may read like an advertisement, but trying to get MacOS to customize itself without resorting to 3-rd party enhancements is usually an exercise in futility.

Comment: Note TotalSpaces does not work any longer on recent versions: Mojave, Catalina. They recommend disabling SIP but nobody should do that.